# joining multiple object to create one object

Tags: java, oop, javafx

now i want create a dumbell shape in javafx i know how to create it and control it in but the problem that i need to treat the shape as multiple three objects not just one object i am newbie in java and oop 
i just want to create dumbell shape that extends extends javafx node
thanks in advance

```
public static void dumbell_builder(Group root) {
Line joiner= line_builder(30,50,20,40,"#00c9e0",1,"joiner");
    Circle rball=ball_builder(30,50, 2,"#00c9e0",true,joiner,"Rball");
    Circle lball=ball_builder(20,40, 2,"#00c9e0",false,joiner,"Lball");
    root.getChildren().addAll(joiner,lball,rball);

}
public static Line line_builder(int sx ,int sy, int ex,int ey,String Stroke,int width,String id) {
    Line line= new Line(sx,sy,ex,ey);
    line.setStrokeWidth(width);
    line.setStroke(Paint.valueOf(Stroke));
    line.setId(id);
    return line;
}
private static Circle ball_builder(int x,int y, int r,String fill,boolean right,Line line,String id) {
    Circle ball=new Circle(x,y,r);
    ball.setFill(Paint.valueOf(fill));
    ball.setId(id);
    ball.setOnMousePressed(event->{
        strtdrag=true;

    });
    ball.setOnMouseDragged(event->{

        if(strtdrag) {
            ball.setCenterY(event.getY());
            ball.setCenterX(event.getX());
                    if (right) {
                        line.setEndY(event.getY());
                        line.setEndX(event.getX());
                    }else {
                        line.setStartY(event.getY());
                       line.setStartX(event.getX());
                    }
            }

    });
    ball.setOnMouseReleased(event ->{
        strtdrag=false;

    });
    return ball;
}
```

here is my trial to create dumbell class

```
   public static void create_dumbell(Group root,double sx,double sy,double ex,double ey) {
DoubleProperty startX = new SimpleDoubleProperty(sx);
DoubleProperty startY = new SimpleDoubleProperty(sy);
DoubleProperty endX   = new SimpleDoubleProperty(ex);
DoubleProperty endY   = new SimpleDoubleProperty(ey);
Line ru = new ControlLine(startX, startY, endX, endY);
Anchor control1 = new Anchor(Color.FORESTGREEN, ru.startXProperty(), ru.startYProperty(), 3);
Anchor control2 = new Anchor(Color.FORESTGREEN, ru.endXProperty(), ru.endYProperty(), 3);
 root.getChildren().addAll(ru,control1,control2);
 }
      class ControlLine extends Line {
    ControlLine(DoubleProperty startX, DoubleProperty startY, DoubleProperty endX, DoubleProperty endY) {
        startXProperty().bind(startX);
        startYProperty().bind(startY);
        endXProperty().bind(endX);
        endYProperty().bind(endY);
        setStrokeWidth(2);
        setStroke(Color.FORESTGREEN.deriveColor(0, 1, 1, 0.5));
    }
}


// a draggable anchor displayed around a point.
class Ball extends Circle {
    Ball(Color color, DoubleProperty x, DoubleProperty y, double radius) {
        super(x.get(), y.get(), radius);
        setFill(color.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.5));
        setStroke(color);
        setStrokeWidth(2);
        setStrokeType(StrokeType.OUTSIDE);
        x.bind(centerXProperty());
        y.bind(centerYProperty());
        enableDrag();
    }
    Ball(Color color, double x, double y, double radius) {
        super(x, y, radius);
        setFill(color.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.5));
        setStroke(color);
        setStrokeWidth(2);
        setStrokeType(StrokeType.OUTSIDE);
        enableDrag();
    }
    // make a node movable by dragging it around with the mouse.
    private void enableDrag() {
        final Delta dragDelta = new Delta();
        setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent -> {
            // record a delta distance for the drag and drop operation.
            dragDelta.x = getCenterX() - mouseEvent.getX();
            dragDelta.y = getCenterY() - mouseEvent.getY();

        });
        setOnMouseReleased(mouseEvent -> getScene().setCursor(Cursor.HAND));
        setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent -> {
            double newX = mouseEvent.getX() + dragDelta.x;
            if (newX > 0 && newX < getScene().getWidth()) {
                setCenterX(newX);
            }
            double newY = mouseEvent.getY() + dragDelta.y;
            if (newY > 0 && newY < getScene().getHeight()) {
                setCenterY(newY);
            }
        });

    }
    // records relative x and y co-ordinates.
    private class Delta { double x, y; }
}
```

Comment: Just put the three nodes in their own `Group`; then you can just treat that `Group` as a single object.

Comment: the program that i am doing is to allow the user click to create the right ball at the position of click and left ball at the second click not just a fixed location or one time

Comment: And how is that relevant to my comment?

Comment: as i think that i can't control the boundaries for each dumbell created
i have updated the question with the my last trial code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a subclass of `Group`, which adds the line and circles to itself. You can also use bindings to keep the line connected to the circles:

```
public class Dumbell extends Group {

    private boolean dragging ;

    public Dumbell() {

        Line joiner = new Line();
        joiner.setId("joiner");
        joiner.setStroke(Paint.valueOf("#00c9e0"));
        joiner.setStrokeWidth(1);

        Circle rball = createBall(30, 50);
        Circle lball = createBall(20, 40);

        joiner.startXProperty().bind(rball.centerXProperty());
        joiner.startYProperty().bind(rball.centerYProperty());
        joiner.endXProperty().bind(lball.centerXProperty());
        joiner.endYProperty().bind(lball.centerYProperty());

        getChildren().addAll(joiner, lball, rball);
    }

    private Circle createBall(double x, double y) {
        Circle ball = new Circle(x, y, 2);
        ball.setFill(Paint.valueOf("#00c9e0"));
        ball.setOnMousePressed(e -> dragging = true );
        ball.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            if (dragging) {
                ball.setCenterX(e.getX());
                ball.setCenterY(e.getY());
            }
        });
        ball.setOnMouseReleased(e -> dragging = false);
        return ball ;
    }
}
```

Then you just need

```
Dumbell dumbell = new Dumbell();
root.getChildren().add(dumbell);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Pane on which you add your shapes and access it instead of the shapes. Is that what you mean?
I don't understand your question entirely since the english is a little broken sorry.

You can also create a custom node by creating a class that extends Pane and then override its layoutChildren() method if you need to have a specific layout for your components.

Comment: @James_D im not sure if i understand the question correctly but if he actually wants it to be treated as a seperate single node that is the easiest way i can think of if he needs a special layout.